# How to define column names in R - ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a R beginner.
I wrote my script for plotting some data using ggplot.
This is what I'm talking about, and IS WORKING!:

```
plotSerie <- ggplot(fileIn, aes(x=DOY_S1, y=S1_VH, fill=variety, group=paste(fileIn$DOY_S1, fileIn$variety, sep="")))+
 geom_boxplot()
```

The problem is that I would like to change the columns to be plotted prior of the ggplot.

```
  pol <- "VH"
  sensor <- "S1"
  type <- "variety" 

  plotSerie <- ggplot(fileIn, aes(x=paste("DOY_",sensor, sep=""), y=paste(sensor,"_", pol, sep=""), fill=type, group= paste(fileIn$paste("DOY_",sensor, sep=""), fileIn$type, sep="")))+

  geom_boxplot()
```

But it doesn't work.

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: why not change the columns prior to plotting, instead of calling functions inside `aes`, which is a bad idea to begin with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a friend of mine helped me with my issue.

I solved my proble adding a column to my data frame for grouping:

```
    sensor <- "S1"
    pol <- "VH"
    type <- "variety"


cc <- paste("DOY_",sensor, sep="")
aa <- fileIn[cc]
bb <- fileIn[paste(type)]

df <- cbind(aa,bb)
names(df) <- c('aa','bb')
fileIn$grp <- as.factor(paste(df$aa, df$bb, sep=""))

plotSerie <- ggplot(fileIn, aes_string(x=paste("DOY_",sensor, sep=""), 
                                   y=paste(sensor,"_",pol, sep=""), 
                                   fill=type, 
                                   group="grp"))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Either change your column names beforehand:

```
colnames(df) <- c('x','y')
```

Or try something like:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Var, y = Freq)) + geom_boxplot() + xlab("Category Name") + ylab("Variable Name")
```

With your example:

```
plotSerie <- ggplot(fileIn, aes(x=DOY_S1, y=S1_VH, fill=variety, group=paste(fileIn$DOY_S1, fileIn$variety, sep=""))) +
 geom_boxplot() + xlab("DOY_S1") + ylab("S1_VH")
```